# How to use data from QR code scanned and do some changes in SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, qr-code

I am new to android studio and app development. I want to scan QR code that will display total price of something and after user click pay, the total price will be deducted from Sqlite database. As for now, I am only able to scan QR code. So I want to know how to retrieve the data and use it to deduct in sqlite?

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String scanResult = result.getText();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan QR code");
    builder.setNeutralButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(ScanQRcode.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("PAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(scanResult));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(scanResult);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you implemented SQLite at all yet? By the code posted it is impossible to tell. I would start by researching how to utilize an SQLite DB and perhaps build a few sample apps working with the data. Then try and add that functionality to your current project.

Comment: Yes i had implemented sqlite, it is just one column and one row since i want to deduct all the price scanned from the same value. However I am not really sure how to pass the scanned data to the database,do subtraction and display the new value after deducting.